# is there any free barcode reader sdk for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-7, barcode

I am developing windows mobile application to scan a product barcode by using in built camera. Can you tell me something about barcode reader sdk which are supporting windows mobile 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7, with the upcoming Mango update, there will be direct access to the camera feed, without having to take a picture of the barcode.  Prior to Mango, there is a library that can be downloaded from Codeplex, called ZXIng (Zebra Crossing).  http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/

Are you developing for Windows Phone, or Windows Mobile?  There is no Windows Mobile 7 - with the complete rewrite, the name changed to Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3):

There is always this library (zxing):

http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/

It does a pretty decent job, and is able to read a number of different barcodes/qrcodes/and so on.

I updated the link to the silverlight version.

You can see the documentation here:
http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/documentation

It's fairly easy to implement, as he's given everything you need for WP7.