# Is there a free barcode scanner SDK for Windows Phone 7 that I can use in my apps?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Is there a free barcode scanner SDK for Windows Phone 7 that I can use in my apps out there? Something like Zbar?

Something that I can access with C# and .NET.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any free barcode reader sdk for Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110246/is-there-any-free-barcode-reader-sdk-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can use [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight ZXing Barcode Scanning Library](http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/), there is a [similar question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110246/is-there-any-free-barcode-reader-sdk-for-windows-phone-7)